# Comments, questions and answers don't trim Unicode U200B when counting characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, unicode

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Y U POSTING UNICODE

Comment: It's a bug.​​​​

Comment: OK!​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: The mouseover in the main page shows a lot of boxes.

Comment: @mmyers what browser?

Comment: mouseover doesn't appear at all for me

Comment: @Ian, me too   .

Comment: IE7.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: And another odd thing, when I copy the Unicode into the comment box, it doesn't show up at all. The character count updates, and backspacing changes the count but doesn't move the cursor.

Comment: @mmyers, the character has zero width

Comment: Ah,   I    see.

Comment: I could have put the zero-width character in the title, too, but then no one would be able to click it. As a test, I *did* use it in the title of a post on a forum I frequent. It's completely unclickable and I am completely happy with that.

Comment: By design, eh? What's the point of enforcing a character limit when you can just fill it with nondisplaying characters? Seriously, where is the sense in that?

Comment: Agree completely.  I'm guessing that it doesn't cause real problems, so It isn't worth addressing.  Nobody is really abusing it.

Comment: Sure, people post short comments all the time.  But who is it hurting?

Comment: Wo​​​​​​​​​​​ot

Comment: [Bug has returned in 2019](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13898/what-the-heck-is-this-invisible-question-and-and-answer-post)

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

Also made it [Zero Width Non Joiner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles) aware.

Enjoy.

Comment: ͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: Was it fixed only for posts, not comments?

Answer (score 10):



Answer (score 6):

In retrospect it seems to only be U200B that is unchecked. I thought it was the whole range.

Comment: What character is that?

Comment: zero width space, rofl http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: P.S. You ruined this whole Question by actually adding content to an answer.

Comment: It's a bug, man. I'm here to have fun, but I'm also here to report bugs properly.

Comment: Well, fair enough.