# You can bypass the comment 15 character minimum by adding spaces

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, character-limit

You can bypass the comment 15 character minimum by adding spaces.

Comment: This is a dupe many times over.

Comment: They know, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/comments-questions-and-answers-dont-trim-unicode-u200b-when-counting-characters

Comment: Yes, please leave this **feature** as is.

Comment: **To close voters**: the issue was *fixed*, not *no longer reproducible*. That close reason is intended for *ephemeral* issues that resolve themselves after a short while, not for actual bugs that are later marked completed. The [tag:status-completed] tag is enough.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog It is not truly fixed on sites with MathJax. See [Crypto.SE meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1199/54184) (that mentions answers, but the technique applies to comments as well).

Comment: @TheforestofReinstateMonica In that case, the proper protocol is to file another bug report.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Frankly, I'm no longer interested in going out of my way to help SE. I was just pointing out that a very close variation of this bug _is_ still reproducible, which I believe is relevant.

Comment: @ab2ReinstateMonicaNow It was retagged by a now-deleted user yesterday.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is technically a bug, but we like the bug and we believe that it should exist for those smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: It requires no intelligence to figure out. Don't give people big heads.

Comment: ... I figured it out, after all! :-P

Comment: Just get rid of the minimum so that everyone can do it.  UIs shouldn't have secret features based on insider knowledge.

Comment: Intelligence might not be the right word but *intent* is, and just forcing users to add paddng characters is pointless. Due consideration should be the only barrier of entry, as it were.

Answer (score 8):

I have been doing this for months. I don't think it's a bug; I think it's a 'feature'. I like it.

Comment: "Been doing this for months" is perfect informal English, there was no need to edit it. It's how English is spoken every day.

Answer (score -5):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

Enjoy.

Comment: Bob Slydell: Well, just a second there, professor. We, uh, we fixed the *glitch*. So he won't be receiving a paycheck anymore, so it'll just work itself out naturally.
Bob Porter: We always like to avoid confrontation, whenever possible. Problem is solved from your end.

Comment: Darn.  (Padding.)

Comment: Boo!56789012345

Comment: This was for the best.

Comment: :-( :-( :-( :-(
(I would have entered one smily face but it was too short a comment)

Comment: I think this is misguided - I for one very nearly opened up a feature-request to get this backpaddingcharactersarepointlessandirritating

Comment: (Igal Tabachnik's are [Office Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space) [references](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqjQDP9KX6E).)