# Comments less than 15 chars?

Tags: support, comments, character-limit

I know this was fixed.
Somehow people still do it.
I just wonder, how?

Comment: Enjoy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/comments-questions-and-answers-dont-trim-unicode-u200b-when-counting-characters - Now keep quiet about it.

Comment: ̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃

Comment: @random: post that as an answer if you want +15.

Comment: ​‎​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​⁪⁪

Comment: w00t!̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃

Comment: I used the tilde char: `~` by typing `CTRL + SHIFT + U` then entering the unicode number `0303`.

Comment: Shut it down. Shut it all down!

Comment: Looks like Bob Dylan got lost listening to his own sat nav GPS car bot doohickey.

Comment: -1 for an invalid haiku.

Comment: What's the fix for the haiku again? 5/7/5?

Comment: There, fixed it.

Comment: +1 For haiku-ing that right there.

Comment: Nice.̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃

Answer (score 6, accepted):

‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: I'm still gonna give random a chance, but if he doesn't do it in like 24 hours you can have it.

Comment: ⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪:-)

Comment: I still don't understand how to do it

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/28795/list

Comment: plz-send-me-the-codez @random I cannot see anything on that link. If I click view source it's blank

Comment: I like that this is now devolving into an exact duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/comments-questions-and-answers-dont-trim-unicode-u200b-when-counting-characters

Comment: One hour to go!

Comment: One hour until what?

Answer (score 5):

Actually I find it annoying, because sometimes I really DO have a concise comment, but am forced to pad it with non-essential junk just to meet the length requirements.

Answer (score 5):

> I know this was fixed.

***"Fixed?"*  It was never  broken!**

It was only changed to prevent the non-stop "bug" submissions.  If one is crafty enough to get around the limitations, then one is usually are smart enough to write a concise comment.

Comment: IMHO it's something we should be allowed to do after gaining a certain amount of rep (like the requests to lift the once-every-5-seconds vote limitation).

Answer (score 1):

The bug is not gone, people...

It stays among us...

**Observe...**