# Tooltip summary of question runs together on linebreaks, formatting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, tooltips, summary

When mousing over the title of a question to get a tooltip summary of the content, any line breaks, code formatting, etc. is lost and the lines just run together. The formatting for the example question is as follows:

> When I compile this program I only get the first capital letter but not the rest example:
>
> Input: ABldjfdslkjfCK
>
> I only get A that is it?
>
> Can someone please help me with this problem. Thanks a lot.

Followed by some example code.

Perhaps this is a browser issue, I don't know. I'm on firefox 3.5.4 and ubuntu 9.10.

[Example Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697777/recursion-using-c-language)

[alt text http://img503.imageshack.us/img503/4974/tooltipexamp.png](http://img503.imageshack.us/img503/4974/tooltipexamp.png)

Comment: Same solution I am looking for too. :-(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320081/how-does-stack-overflow-display-tooltip-for-the-questions

Answer (score 1):

In the tiny bit of web development I have done, I seem to remember that Firefox does not support line breaks in title text while IE does. As a test, I checked the tooltip for the haiku-ified question "[Comments less than 15 chars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28792/comments-less-than-15-chars)" and it shows up properly for me in IE7.