# A question with a title but without a body. Is it possible or is it a bug?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, rendering

[Is it possible to use a VHD for dual boot and VPC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/91049/is-it-possible-to-use-a-vhd-for-dual-boot-and-vpc)

This question does have a title and two answers, but not an actually question body. Although, the tags section that usually located on the right, in this page is moved to the bottom.

Is it a bug? or what happened there?

[image]

I get this picture on: Firefox 3.6, Chrome 6, and IE9. Even when I logged out.

It turns out that this is not a browser specific issue, as the question body is miss from the actual HTML. Here is (what I think) the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="question-header">

    <h1><a href="/questions/91049/is-it-possible-to-use-a-vhd-for-dual-boot-and-vpc" class="question-hyperlink">Is it possible to use a VHD for dual boot and VPC?</a></h1>

</div>



<div id="mainbar">

<div id="question">



    <div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow" id="adzerk1">

    </div>



















<div id="answers">



    <a name="tab-top"></a>

    <div id="answers-header">
```

Comment: `[status-you're-hallucinating]`

Comment: That said, this is an actual, valid bodyless question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/comments-questions-and-answers-dont-trim-unicode-u200b-when-counting-characters

Comment: But as you can see, the content on the left (tagged, linked, related etc) moved down the page.

Comment: Head without a body, must be haloween soon.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: If you see a blank space above the body then it's because you're using an ad blocker.  Might not want to, um, advertise that fact.

Comment: What browser is that?

Comment: Is is a bug, but it depends on what your definition of is is

Comment: I'm using AdBlock, and with < 200 rep on SF, there's a blank where the ad is supposed to be. However, the question body shows up fine. XP + FF 3.6.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this turned out to be a specific issue for our network.

As it turns out that our internet is behind a host that extract this text, from some reason.

Sorry about this post, and it can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: I can't understand why you get the question, and I don't. The question is miss from the actual HTML, and it's not a css problem.

Comment: @Mendy: do you see the question if you log off?

Comment: @Kop I logged out and I get the same input.

Comment: @Mendy: try with a proxy such as https://aniscartujo.com/webproxy/ to see if it's an issue somehow tied to your IP address

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce in Chrome 7, IE 8, or Firefox 3.6.

Comment: It's not a browser issue, as the question is missed from the actual HTML. I'll post the relevant HTML in the question.